# Script for changing CSV into Key Value (KV) format

Tags: shell, csv

I have a  CSV file with data as below:

```
row_identifier,DBNAME,tblsps_name,Cur_size,Max_size,Used,Free,Percentage
tablespace,MRETF,RERETOSB15_DATA,51200,45600,14284,31316,31
tablespace,MRETF,SPOTLIGHT_DATA,500,2000,259,1741,13
tablespace,MRETF,DDLAUDITING,25,25,2,23,8
```

I want the output in the following format:

```
tablespace,MRETF,tblsps_name:RERETOSB15_DATA,Cur_size:51200,Max_size:45600,Used:14284,Free:31316,Percentage:31
tablespace,MRETF,tblsps_name:SPOTLIGHT_DATA,Cur_size:500,Max_size:2000,Used:259,Free:1741,Percentage:13
```

and so on..

Is this possible to get the output like the above key:value format?

Comment: In general, yes, it will possible. Some more information might be helpful, like: Have you tried already something? Or are you interested in specific shells, like bash? Are some command required, like cat, sed, awk, pr, etc?

Comment: Hi. yes, it can be in korn or bourne shell. sed / awk will be helpful.

Comment: also asked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462461/4667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time at least pretend that you tried something ;-)

```
awk -F"," 'FNR > 1 {print $1","$2",tblsps_name:"$3",Cur_size:"$4",Max_size:"$5",Used:"$6",Free:"$7",Percentage:"$8}' your.csv
```

`-F","` is field separator, `FNR > 1` skip first header line, `$1` is first column and so on